# Westernmost and easternmost locations that Charles V visited in his empire?

Tags: europe, 16th-century, charles-v, habsburg

Charles V (1500 – 1558) famously was ruler over an ["empire on which the sun never set"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_empire_on_which_the_sun_never_sets). It included large parts of Europe and also colonies in the new world. Charles V was born in the Low Countries and later ruled from Spain, which suggests a mainly North-to-South trajectory for his life in territories that stretched also across continents and from the distant West to the remote East.

What were the westernmost and easternmost locations within the Empire that Charles V visited during his lifetime? (I take it that a visit to the colonies by such a ruler was never contemplated at that time.)

Comment: It was not extensive, but from school texts there was no travelling out of Europe. So, I would assume Galicia (NW Spain) and Germany/Austria. Note that he spent his youth in Central Europe, maybe he travelled further East before his crowning.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "settled"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Emperor Charles V lived out his entire life on the European continent, with a few short visits to the north African coast. He definitely never visited the colonies in the Americas. Here's what I was able to find:

*Easternmost Location*: **Vienna**, in 1532, to fight off the armies of the Ottoman Empire.

*Westernmost Location*: **Seville**, in 1526, for his marriage to Isabella of Portugal. A close runner up is the **Monastery of Yuste**, in western Spain, which he retired to in 1557 until his death in 1558. He may have visited Portugal or Galicia further west, but I was unable to find any record of it.

References: The Wikipedia page for [Charles V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_V,_Holy_Roman_Emperor), the Encyclopedia Britannica page for [Charles V](http://www.britannica.com/biography/Charles-V-Holy-Roman-emperor), and [The Autobiography of the Emperor Charles V](https://books.google.com/books?id=aFsTAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 3):

*Westernmost Location*: Charles V was in Galicia, in A Coruña and **Santiago de Compostela** (42°52′N, 08°32′W) in 1520, where he called for the *Cortes* (Parliament) of Castille:

Ref.:

- [Biography of CHARLES V](http://www.mcnbiografias.com/app-bio/do/show?key=carlos-i-rey-de-espanna-y-v-emperador-de-alemania).
- [*Carlos V. Emperador y Hombre*](https://books.google.es/books?id=kl0PCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT50), by Juan Antonio Vilar Sánchez.